# Research on Social Network Sites, Test Data Required

Tags: facebook, twitter, data-mining, prediction

Where can i have a data set to make predictive analysis in my data mining project? does Face book twitter provide any of its data set for Research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both platforms do not explicitly provide sample data. You didn't specify what data you're interested, profiles, posts, etc., but you should have.

As of the Graph API v2.0 changes, the search for public Facebook Posts has been deprecated, so you'll have a hard time getting data out. Profiles use now the app-scoped user_ids, which also makes it harder. The only thing I could imagine is to use the `/search` endpoint to search for user names. But this doesn't make much sense, and the data you'd get without having explicit permission from the users is not really useful.

Concerning Twitter, you could use the use the Streaming API to consume tweets from the platform, see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public